# How to change size of spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner

can we change the size of popup window which shows when click on spinner,

actually its look very wide and i want to reduce the width of pop window, but dn't knw how is it possible

Answer (score 2):

You can change these settings in the layout file. The hello-spinner tutorial is very useful.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Add a new XML file to your layout folder.

Example: spinnerLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="14pt"         
              android:textColor="#FF8B1500"
              android:gravity="center"/>
```

Change the adapter resource to your new layout file:

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.sound, R.layout.spinnerLayout);
```

Comment: i n\want to change the size of spinner popup window

Comment: Ok. if i am finding the solution will give you as soon as possible.